# How can I initialize a jQuery plugin (noUISlider) included via browserify-shim?

Tags: jquery, bower, gulp, browserify, nouislider

### Greetings, Overfluvians!

I'm working on a Swiss Army build system ([Gulp](http://gulpjs.com), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), [Bower](http://bower.io), [BrowserSync](http://www.browsersync.io/), [RunSequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence), [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)), but trying to get a jQuery plugin shimmed into the build and the DOM has me stumped.

I've put together a sandbox repo if you'd like to quickly reproduce the issue for yourself:  **[gulp-browserify-bower-test](https://github.com/krry/demo-gulp-browserify-bower-jquery)**. If you're a brave soul who builds apps in your head, please proceed.

The issue I'm trying to resolve is: ***how do I properly shim or require jQuery*** so that dependencies are met without unneeded bloat in the distributed build?

### Here are the relevant files and their relevant contents:

#### 1. The pre-browserified client-side script `bundle.js` that seeks to initialize the slider:

```js
var $ = require('jquery')

var maskedinput = require('maskedinput')

function maskInputs() {
  return $('input#zip').mask('99999')
}
maskInputs()

var nouislider = require('nouislider')

function initSlider() {
  return $('div#slider').noUISlider()
}

initSlider()
```

#### 2. A page `index.html` which contains the slider element to be initialized:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NoUISlider Gulp Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="nouislider"></div>
    <input type="tel" id="zip">
    <script src="/dist/js/all.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### 3. `bower.json` which brings in the jQuery and jQuery plugins

```json
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "~2.1.1", // not sure if need jquery via bower or not
  "jquery.maskedinput": "~1.3.1",
  "nouislider": "~7.0.7"
}
```

#### 4. `package.json` which witchcrafts the modules into browserify shims, setting their exported names and their dependencies:

```json
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
"browser": {
  "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "maskedinput": "./bower_components/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput.min.js",
  "nouislider": "./bower_components/nouislider/distribute/jquery.nouislider.all.min.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "global:jQuery",
  "maskedinput": {
    "exports": "maskedinput",
    "depends": [ "jquery:$" ]
  },
  "nouislider": {
    "exports": "nouislider",
    "depends": [ "jquery:$" ]
  }
},
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "~2.1.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "browserify": "^5.11.0",
  "browserify-shim": "^3.6.0",
  "gulp": "^3.7.0",
  "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.0.0"
}
```

I've tried using the bower version of jquery too, substituting this for the npm version in `package.json`:

```json
==== try this ====
"jquery": "./bower_components/jquery/lib/jquery.js",
==== or this ====
"jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
```

#### 5. `gulpfile.js` which contains the browserify gulp task:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp')
var browserify = require('browserify')
var stream = require('vinyl-source-stream')

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
  return browserify('bundle.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(stream('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
})

gulp.task('default', ['browserify'])
```

### The roadblock

Note that I'm able to `require('maskedinput')` in my client-side js, but when I try to `require('nouislider')`, I see a console error that seems to say NoUISlider is not finding its jQuery dependency: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined"` when trying to initialize the NoUISlider.

Once again, here's the sandbox set up for easy reproduction of the issue:  **[gulp-browserify-bower-test](https://github.com/krry/demo-gulp-browserify-bower-jquery)**

What gives? How should I be including jQuery and these plugins?

Is there a better way to do this with either `bower` or `Browserify` but not both? I found several modules hosted on `npm` and `bower` where the build, module type, and general quality tended to vary, so I thought it wise to accommodate both package managers.

Comment: Can I show you how I would do it by Grunt?

Comment: Have you tried not shimming jquery? If you install via npm, you shouldn't need a shim or an alias in the `browser` section of your package.json.

Comment: Does `$ = require('jquery')` mean jQuery isn't available as `window.jQuery`?

Comment: window.jQuery = $ = require('jquery') will ensure get what you want

Comment: @IanLim It'd be great to see how you'd do this with Grunt. And I'll try attaching jQuery to the `window`, though I thought the browserify-shim was making this available in the global namespace already (from package.json): ```"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "global:jQuery"```

Comment: @Ben I have jQuery directly via npm ```"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "~2.1.1"
}```

Comment: @Lg102 in my demo repo, `window.jQuery` is not available, but `window.$` is. Could this be a clue?

Comment: Not merely a clue: That is the answer.

Comment: Updated the test repo with the addition from @Lg102 for anyone game to help debug. http://github.com/krry/gulp-browersify-bower-test

Answer (score 0):

noUiSlider extends window.jQuery or window.Zepto. As neither of those is available, extending the prototype (fn) wont work. Simply adding:

```
var jQuery = $;
```

Should do.

Comment: Okay I've caught the scent but haven't found the carcass yet. It's got little to do with your awesome slider library, just happened to be the one I wanted to use :) I tried adding that line to the scripts that compile to the DOM but Browserify still complains that jQuery is not defined.

Comment: I've look though your code for a bit: You have several issues with variable scoping. For example: `var jQuery` is defined within a function, but used in an other. You should start by making sure you are correctly scoping your variables + properties on `global`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I got things working today by changing the variable name of jQuery in the browserify-shims from "$" to "jQuery". Then I removed the shim for jQuery which apparently wasn't being used in the global namespace like I thought it was. Check out [package.json](https://github.com/krry/demo-gulp-browserify-bower-jquery/blob/master/package.json) to see what I mean.

Comment: If you want to update your answer to something about making sure that jquery is named "jQuery" in the shims in order for the plugins to recognize it, I'll humbly accept.